# jQAssistant maven plugin cannot connect to remote neo4j server

Tags: maven, neo4j, jqassistant

I am trying to setup a remote jQAssistant Team Server.
Neo4J Desktop is installed on a server running a blank test dbms. I modified the neo4j.config to allow remote connections `server.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0`, the rest remaied default.
I can access Neo4J remotely via webbrowser `*server-local-IP-adress*:7474` leads to the neo4j browser and after logging in I get
`You are connected as user jqa to neo4j://*server-local-IP-adress*:7687`.

In our Maven project, I removed all our jQAssistant plugin settings and just added the plugin and profile settings as described in [this guide](http://101.jqassistant.org/setting-up-a-team-server/index.html). I have done this as a POC before attempting to make our current profile settings work with the remote server - another question might be coming :)

Running `mvn clean install -Pnightly` I get: 
`[INFO] Connecting to store at 'bolt://server-local-IP-adress:7687' (username=jqa)`

but immediatley after the build fails:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.buschmais.jqassistant:jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.8.0:scan (default-cli) on project ****: Execution default-cli of goal com.buschmais.jqassistant:jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.8.0:scan failed: Connection to the database terminated. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. -> [Help 1]`

I am not aware of any non-default encryption settings. Any ideas as to how I could solve this?

Thanks!
Patrick

Comment: It should work as described. Which versions of jQAssistant and Neo4j are you using?